# Matlab - Interpolation of non-monotonic scattered 3d - data using griddata

Tags: matlab, interpolation, data-fitting

My question is about using griddata as a substitute for interp2 in matlab as my data is not monotonic. I have extracted data for x_measured, y_measured, z_measured and would like to interpolate z at specified Points (x,y).

This code works:

```
z = griddata(x_measured,y_measured, z_measured,x,y,'linear')
```

This obviously doesn't as the data is non monotonic:

```
z = interp2(x_measured,y_measured, z_measured,x,y,'linear')
```

I'm wondering why griddata works. griddata returns a value using linear Interpolation as specified in the function call. Is there a fundamental difference between the two algorithms?

Comment: You already know the difference: `interp2` expects monotonic data, `griddata` doesn't. `griddata` needs to do a lot more work to find the input values to interpolate between, the search is trivial if the data is monotonic.

Comment: Thanks Cris! This was  my issue. it's rather the search for the right values than the Interpolation itself.